# Using nrrd.read to parse nrrd file is very slow/heavy, how to fix it?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am using nrrd.read to parse a large nrrd file (32MB). But my laptop freezes every time.
the code is just as follows:

```
vol, metaVol = nrrd.read('data/annotation_10_ccf17.nrrd');
```

And the nrrd file can be found with this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dllwj3u19bsfd4c/annotation_10_ccf17.nrrd?dl=0

Is there a way to apply parallel processing, or any method, to make it computationally lighter?

My laptop specifications:
CPU: Core-i5, RAM:8 GB

a minimal working example:

```
import nrrd
vol, metaVol = nrrd.read('data/annotation_10_ccf17.nrrd'); 
img_left = []
for i in range(vol.shape[1]):
    #print(int(initial + pace*i))
    row = []
    for j in range(int(vol.shape[2]/2)):
        number = int(slice_number + initial_beta + initial_alpha + pace_beta*i + pace_alpha*j)
        if number < 0:
            number = 0
        if number >= vol.shape[0]:
            number = vol.shape[0] - 1
        row += [vol[number][i][j]]
    img_left += [row]
```

Comment: Check the amount of allocated memory is quite small and there is still some space left. 32 MB seems relatively small. Note that if you call this in a parallel code with multiple processes, each process will load it and the storage device will quickly be saturated. Solutions include loading the file once and share the loaded data between processes, or put the file in a virtual storage device stored in memory. The OS should already cache the file in memory (especially on HDD). Can you tell us more about the context (eg. where this line is used) or provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you for your comment. yes as a minimal working example, I added to the question text.

Comment: Indeed. The problem comes from the huge amount of memory allocated by the nrrd package function. It takes 4.5 GiB of RAM which I find really not normal regarding the input size. I think you should open an [issue on the package github](https://github.com/mhe/pynrrd/issues). I think it is either due to a bug, a bad usage or a corrupted file.